# What did Gauss think about V. A. Lebesgue's proof of quadratic reciprocity?

Tags: mathematics, gauss

The proof can be found [here (pdf)](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ewcastryc/reciprocity.pdf). It was published in 1838 and Gauss lived until 1855, so I would guess that he read it. Did Gauss say anything about it?

Comment: Oswald Baumgart, *Über das quadratische Reciprocitätsgesetz.* Ph.D. dissertation, University of Göttingen 1885 (Dresden: B. G. Teubner 1885), [104 pp.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%C3%9Cber_das_quadratische_reciprocit%C3%A4tsges/6zytBZ2VaCMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover) makes no mention of such commentary by Gauss. Some of Gauss's correspondence with other scientists is available in book form, but only some of these books are accessible as Google scans. I have not found anything relevant yet in freely available scans.